# Can I open a modal with URL parameters in Django to edit a form?

Tags: django

thank you in advance. I am creating a Django template that allows users to add / edit families information. I would like the ability to add my edit forms to a modal but am having issues passing the parameters of the URL.

url:

```
url(r'^family/(?P<pk>\d+)-(?P<nav_key>[A-Za-z]{4})-(?P<nav_id>\d+)-(?P<sub_key>[A-Za-z]{4})-(?P<sub_id>\d+)/$', family_view, name='family_detail_sub_key_id'),
```

HTML

```
<a href>:
<!-- This is where I need assistance with opening the modal -->
```

Again, thank you

Comment: You'll need to give more details. What issues? Passing the parameters where? What does that URL refer to?

Comment: Sorry, ok. So If I do the normal <a href="{% url 'family_detail_sub_key_id' pk=family_detail.id nav_key='pers' nav_id=person_detail.id sub_key='viol' sub_id=violation.id %}">Click to Edit</a> and add the normal data-toggle="modal" and data-target="#editForm", the modal will open but the form will not work. I can easily take the user to a new page to edit the form but want to have a modal overlay on the current page. Thank you for you response